# Issue with simple PHP script on Joomla page, only on IE. Long load times

Tags: php, mysql, internet-explorer, joomla

I wrote a PHP script that pulls less than 200 rows out of a MySQL DB that has 5 columns.  It is really rather simple and I have used a common variant of this on other pages.

The difference is that this is now inside a Joomla page.

The page loads fine on Firefox and Chrome but in Internet Explorer it takes a really long time to load (minutes).

Is there any known issue between any of these components that could cause a problem like this.

Thank you for any help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

PHP script handling on server by webserver. And it does not matter what browser did you use.
Maybe you have some JavaScript code?

Comment: The whole page will load except for the table generated by the PHP which comes a while later.

Answer (score 0):

There is no obvious reason that the use of IE would cause a database to run slower - or Joomla for that matter. Particularly heavy DOM manipulation in the page can bring older PCs to a halt with IE - but that would be most pages within the site not just one specific page.

How is your script being called - have you built it into a module or component or plugin? Could it be being called multiple times?  Is it actually being called by javascript/ajax from within the page?

If you turn on debug mode can you see how many database queries are being run by the slow page? Is your code being executed multiple times by accident - perhaps in a loop.

Is it one query returning 200 rows - or a loop with 200 iterations carrying out one query on each iteration?

Are you testing IE immediately after testing the other browsers. Could it be a db query throttling issue due to an overloaded database?